# Why I'm having this css background-image referencing issue?

Tags: html, css, deployment, server, netlify

This is fine:

```css
background-image: url(./dir/img.jpg);
```

but, I do get a 404 when trying to refer to an image using this method:

```html
index.html

<div style="--url: url(./dir/img.jpg);"></div>
```

```css
css

background-image: var(--url);
```

It works fine in local server, but when it's deployed, it won't work.

Note:

- I'm not trying to access the root. The path given is correct.
- I do not manage the back-end, I use [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com).

I believe it has something to do with cdn that is configured by netlify and so far my solution is to **provide full path: https://example.com/parent/child/image.jpg**

The 404 error on dev tools console shows a cdn link — I believe:

```
Error: https://d33wubrfki0l68.example.net/parent/child/image.jpg
Works: https://d33wubrfki0l68.example.net/parent/child/[somehashes–idk]/image.jpg
```

instead of:

```
https://example.com/parent/child/image.jpg
```

Please enlighten me.

Comment: Relative URLs in external stylesheets are resolved against the URL of that stylesheet, not your main document. So, where is your stylesheet located in this example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it works on the local server there must be a problem with the image or the server, not the code.

- Can you access the image directly from your web browser?
- Double check if the server's folder structure is the same local server's folder structure. Also, usually we use "/" to specify root folder or "dir" (without slash and dot) for relative location.
- Are your styles updated? Try shift+f5
- If nothing listed above will work, press F12 and check the error message. Maybe it's not a 404 error.